# Autotools AC_DEFINE doesn't wơrk

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I'm trying to define a C preprocessor variable "DEBUG" (#define DEBUG) to activate debug logging in an opensource project, it uses GNU Autotools. So I put a line

```
AC_DEFINE(DEBUG, 1, [My description for DEBUG])
```

in *configure.ac*.

But what? 
After regenerating the config.h

```
autoheader && ./config.status
```

I look at the content of config.h and see this

```
/* My description for DEBUG */  
/* #undef DEBUG */
```

What the heck happened here? Other similar C preprocessor variables (by the project) are defined in the same way. They all appeared "#define"'d and uncommented, why mine becomes "#undef"'d and commented out?
So I tried many ways to do it, not just this way, I mimic the way other symbols by the project is defined. Tried all kinds of *value*, from 1 to TRUE, FALSE, all kinds of *variable*, from "DEBUG" to "FOOBAR", "KJJJ".... But it still works like that, I'm  completely frustrated.

---

More info:

When looking at *config.h.in*, I see all the lines are like this:

```
#undef SOMEVARIABLE
```

(Including my define AND **the ones that appear validly #defined'd in *config.h***.)

When I don't run *autoheader* and just change the line of my variable in config.h.in to

```
#define DEBUG
```

then generate *config.h*, then my DEBUG variable appears validly #define'd in *config.h*

*Autoconf version 2.67
*The project I'm working on is [ibus](http://code.google.com/p/ibus/)

Comment: If you just want to define it to activate debugging, you don't need to edit configure.ac. Just run configure with CPPFLAGS=-DDEBUG

Comment: Run `autoreconf`, not `autoheader`. `autoreconf` will pickup changes to `configure.ac`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `autoheader` modifies `config.h.in`, but not `config.status`.  `config.status` does not know about the change you have made to `configure.ac`, and does not know to do substitutions for `DEBUG`. It will not be updated until you run `autoconf` and the resulting `configure` script.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `autoreconf` instead of calling `autoconf`, `automake` et al manually.

Comment: I tried that already, just talking about the config.h here, and it's changed everytime I modify configure.ac.

Comment: The actual problem was, there's an error that stops autoreconf. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

please place the line `AC_DEFINE` before `AC_OUTPUT` .